# Шифрование по слову

Tags: криптография, шифрование

Необходимо подобрать метод шифрования для передачи текстовых сообщений. Требования всего два:

1. Ключом для шифровки-расшифровки должна служить произвольная строка введенная пользователем (слово или словосочетание).
2. Надежность и криптоустойчивость, насколько это возможно.

Какой метод шифрования лучше выбрать?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ваши хотелки вполне подробно описываются стандартом [RFC-2898](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2898.txt) - иными словами *Password-Based Cryptography Specification 2.0*, если рассказывать нормальным русским языком делается так:

1. Берется ключевое слово (условно *password* или *passphrase*)
2. Генерируется правильным ГСЧ случайный набор соли - *salt* - достаточной длины не хуже 64 бит
3. По алгоритму/хэшу *PBKDF2* вычисляется ключ в виде `key=pbkdf2(password+salt)` - рекомендуемое количество итераций >= 4096
4. Выбирается симметричный алгоритм шифрования с длиной ключа не менее 256 бит, рекомендуется *AES*
5. Выбирается правильный алгоритм выравнивания (*padding*), например *PKCS7*
6. Выбирается правильный алгоритм смешивания блоков - рекомендуется *CBC*
7. Далее шифруем.

С точки зрения Java это означает выбор ГСЧ `SecureRandom`

Выбор шифрования:

```
Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS7Padding");
```

А для вычисления ключа надо использовать:

```
SecretKeyFactory skf = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("PBKDF2WithHmacSHA256");
```

*P.S.* Забыл сказать, что все равно найдется *капитан очевидность*, который скажет, что все это неправильно, и все равно это ненадежно потому что бла-бла :)

Comment: Педанты с [Crypto SE](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/20963) также рекомендуют результат PBKDF2 использовать не напрямую, а прогонять через HKDF

Comment: Ну началось - я же говорил :) В криптографии есть такой термин [змеиное масло](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snake_oil_(cryptography)) :)